# UNetbootin: 13.04_Live vs. 13.04_Hdmedia vs. 13.04_NetInstall?

Tags: 13.04, usb, unetbootin

I have the Ubuntu 13.04 desktop-i386 downloaded but there are multiple choices in UNetbootin for the distribution and I don't know what to choose.

Answer (score 2):

You need to choose Diskimage instead of choosing a distribution, and browse for the file that you downloaded, and choose that for creating the USB.  See image below.

[image]